# POWERSHELL - WINDOWS REGISTRY - How to have path with "*" like 'hkcr:\*\shell'

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I'm a bit noob in PowerShell. I have to suppress a registry entry to remove the context menu option in explorer.exe "Upload to ShareX"

This value is located in : `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ShareX` [It's also in directory but it have no effect when i delete the "directory" one]

So i tried to remove this item in PowerShell by using :

1st exemple : (not working)

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
set-location 'hkcr:\*\shell'
```

*+ set-location 'hkcr:*\shell'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument : (:) [Set-Location], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand*

2nd exemple : (not working)

```
remove-item -path Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ShareX -force -confirm:$false
```

or

```
remove-item -path 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ShareX' -force -confirm:$false
```

I can't get the * value :) PowerShell commands took it as "The Joker"

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: You need to escape the wildcard. [This IDERA PowerTip may help.](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/escape-wildcards)

Comment: thanks for you answer i will try this : https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/escape-wildcards

Comment: I have no success in my tests :( can you show me please the way to use escape wildcards with this command : {remove-item -path 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\''*\shell\ShareX' -force -confirm:$false} please ?

Comment: ``Remove-Item -Path 'HKCR:\`*\Shell\ShareX' -force -confirm:$false`` - note carefully the _single_ quote around the pathname, and the _backtick_ immediately before the wildcard asterisk.

Comment: You are a king ! it works ! thanks a lot !

Comment: i must learn that ` is not '

Comment: Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                 CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                 ---------------
HKCR                                   Registry      HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT                                                                                                

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-Item -Path 'HKCR:\`*\Shell\ShareX' -force -confirm:$false

Comment: I've "proposed" it as a formal answer; if you click on the check mark, it shows that the solution worked and marks the question as answered (and incidentally tosses me a few points of rep on the site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the wildcard in your command. This is described in [IDERA's PowerTip](https://community.idera.com/database-tools/powershell/powertips/b/tips/posts/escape-wildcards); if you quote the path with single quotes <kbd>'</kbd> (usually on the key just to the left of <kbd>ENTER</kbd>), you prefix the wildcard with a single backtick <kbd>`</kbd> (usually the key in the upper-left corner, immediately above <kbd>TAB</kbd>). If you use *double* quotes <kbd>"</kbd>, you may need to double the backtick.

```
Remove-Item -Path 'HKCR:\`*\Shell\ShareX' -Force -Confirm:$false
```

should do what you want.

Comment: french keybpard rules :)

Comment: I use the US-International driver on a US physical keyboard, so that's the key locations I used. I have no idea where those keys appear on a French (or French Canadian) keyboard.:)